# How can i list active docker containers with curl?

Tags: docker

How can I list active docker containers with curl? Is it possible?
E.g I have 3 running containers on server and I want to get list of this containers with curl.
Maybe you have any other idea?

Thanks for help.

Comment: What have you already tried?  What problems are you running into?  Why `curl` instead of, say, `docker ps`, or a language-native Docker SDK?

Comment: Yes, this can be done with an URL like `.../containers/json` for details see https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41

Answer (score 0):

You have several ways to request a remote docker hosts.

Using the docker command with the H (host) flag (to achieve it the docker host configuration has to specify that it allows remote client) :

```
docker -H hostname  foo-docker-cmd
```

or still use the engine [API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24/) that relies on the docker daemon such as :

```
GET /containers/json
```

> The daemon listens on unix:///var/run/docker.sock but you can Bind
> Docker to another host/port or a Unix socket.

Note that to use curl with the engine api, you need cURL 7.40 or later to be able to use [the `--unix-socket` flag](https://superuser.com/questions/834307/can-curl-send-requests-to-sockets).

Comment: (Remember that anyone who can access the Docker socket at all can pretty trivially root the system; you really really don't want to expose it on a network port.)